# Remove mention column globally

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

There is about 50 folders in my Outlook in the workplace, which has been forcefully migrated to Office 365 by the powers. One huge annoyance is that now every folder includes an inch wide `mention` column which eats up space I badly need for the `received` column.

Is there any way to remove `mention` column globally w/o having to go into each of the 50 some folders and right-click/choose remove this column manually?

If anyone knows how to remove the column with a little bell icon called `reminder` that you should mention as well!

Comment: Try doing it to one folder and then:  `View > Change View (in Current View group) > Apply Current View to Other Mail Folders`

Comment: This is super cool! Once I noticed "apply to subfolders" check mark on the bottom after bursting a vessel seeing how a checkbox on the folder did not apply to subfolders, it went honkey dorey.